# Adding parameters to QueryString from ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, action-filter

I am trying to write a custom `ActionFilter` which will append a request id to the `QueryString` if it doesn't already have one.

Something like this :

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        Controller controller = (Controller)filterContext.Controller;
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        // New request
        if (request.QueryString[REQUEST_ID_KEY] == null)
        {
            string requestId = Utility.GetNewUniqueId();
            controller.Session[REQUEST_ID_KEY] = requestId;

            ////////////////////////////////////////
            // Add request id to query string ...???
            ////////////////////////////////////////

            return;
        }

    }
```

One way to add the parameter to the query string which I found was to redirect the action to itself with the request id added to the route values, like this :

```
  RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
  redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", actionName);
  redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", controllerName);
  redirectTargetDictionary.Add(REQUEST_ID_KEY, requestId);

  filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
```

But this kind of seems like a hack. Is there a better way to add parameters to the `QueryString`? (note that my aim is to achieve a `ActionFitler` which rewrites urls, so I have to pass the parameter in the `QueryString`).

Comment: Did you ever find a better way than the redirect-to-self?

Comment: Afaik, wasnt able to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that by the time the routing engine has been engaged you won't be able to re-write URLs. Routing doesn't really work that way.

You can however manipulate the action values that get used to invoke an Action by using a filter. [Phil Haack has an article explaining this exact approach.](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/21/manipulating-action-method-parameters.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Adding a parameter to the action wouldn't work for me, as I would want it to be available in the post back too.